# How to add a sub application (developed with asp.net mvc) in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, http-status-code-404, dynamics-365, subapplication

I want to add a sub application in Dynamics 365 IIS site app, and I had copied all dlls to my app 'bin' folder, but it still not work, and the page throw the '404' error.

Is there any way else to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate supported solutions:

1. You have to host it in IIS as a separate website, then probably use it in an CRM IFRAME
2. Develop it as HTML webresources within CRM

Don't involve the Dynamics BIN or ISV folders, as they are unsupported/non-recommended approaches.

Comment: 1. I tried，but CRM IFRAME can not load my app js files.
2.I used RAZOR in my VIEW，Is weresources support?

Comment: I solved by the first way you provide,Thanks for the answer.